# Proper way to use Generics in this example?

Tags: java, generics

```
FileReader fileReader = null;
Object reader = null;
String dataRow = null;

fileReader = new FileReader(new File(fileLocation));
if (extension.equals("csv")) 
{
    reader = new CSVReader(fileReader);
} 
else 
{
    reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
}  

while (null != (dataRow = reader.readLine())) 
{
    ...
}
```

The idea is to use different types depending on the file type in order to remove duplicated code. However, I get an error on the last line, since reader is type Object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Depends on what `CSVReader` you're using. If you just need `readLine` and open/close type things might be easiest to just make a wrapper class yourself. The two CSV libs I found by searching (you should link to what you're using) both extend off of `Object` so you'd need to wrap at least the CSV class.

Comment: You don't want to use generics, you want to use polymorphism. So the type of `reader` should be some type that both `CSVReader` and `BufferedReader` descend from, and that defines a method called `readLine()`.

Comment: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: So you can see the definition of the `CSVReader` class [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVReader.java#l34). Unfortunately, its closest ancestor to `BufferedReader` is `Object`. It looks like your best solution is to take the suggestion of @DaveNewton and create a wrapper class. This wrapper class would descend from the Java `Reader` class and would take a CSVReader in its constructor. Then, you'd have to implement the `Reader` interface in terms of `CSVReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could make 2 methods:

```
public String read(CSVReader c){
    return c.readLine();
}

public String read(BufferedReader br){
    return br.readLine();
}
```

Then, in your current code:

```
if(extension.equals("csv"))
    dataRow = read(new CSVReader(fileReader));
else
    dataRow = read(new BufferedReader(fileReader));
```

This overloading would remove the need for a wrapper class.

If you really want to use a wrapper class, I recommend having this somewhere:

```
public interface MyIO{
    public String readLine();
}

public class MyBr extends BufferedReader implements MyIO{}

public class MyCSV extends CSVReader implements MyIO{}
```

Then, in your code:

```
MyIO reader;
if(extension.equals("csv"))
    reader = new MyCSV(fileReader);
else
    reader = new MyBr(fileReader);
```

You'd notice that both are the same number of lines of code and (in my opinion) the methods are easier to follow.

Comment: Clever! I will give this shot.

Comment: I'd consider what I mentioned this in my comment to include `close`, although they both already implement `Closeable` it might be nice to avoid the cast. I'm ambivalent on this, though, and would probably do both to see if it's worth it.

Comment: (Although if it was a throwaway thing, or this was a small part of the system, I'd probably just do the two `read` methods that specialize on the type as in your first suggestion.)

Comment: I think that the wrapper class is the way to go. How can I reconcile the fact that BufferedReader.readLine() returns a string, but CSVReader.readLine() returns an array? (Obviously declaring dataRow as a String will not work)

Comment: The issue with the methods apparoach is that declaring a new BufferedReader every time you call read() will just keep reading the first line in the file, no?

Comment: About the multiple lines: my bad, I didn't realise that you were using this code repeatedly. Unless you also want to keep a running total of your strings lengths and then use `seek`, you'd have to use the wrapper.

Comment: About the array vs String problem: this breaks the wrapper solution as it is. If you need a String, you'd need to convert the array anyway, so I would implement a `readLine` in `MyCSV` that calls `super.readLine` and converts that array to a String.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help. I actually need a string from BufferedReader and I need an array from CVSReader, so there doesn't seem to be a nice way to do it except to duplicate the while loop with different Readers.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering to point out that it is certainly possible to use generics even if your types are not cooperative. You'll just have to define specializations for each type separately. I'll just put a sketch in Java 8 here. Not sure what you mean by 'Proper way', there are pros and cons to everything...especially in Java.

Somewhat simpler way, putting generic code in a common superclass:

```
interface GenericExample {
    interface InputGenericCode<Input> {

        /**
         * This is implemented in subtypes. 
         * 
         * @param x
         * @return
         */
        String readLine(Input x);

        default void genericAlgorithm(Input x) {
            // algorithm expressed generically here...
            for (;;) {
                String lineString = readLine(x);
                System.out.println("" + lineString);
            }
        }
    }

    public class BufferedReaderInputGenericCode implements InputGenericCode<BufferedReader> {

        @Override
        public String readLine(BufferedReader x) {
            try {
                return x.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public class CSVReaderInputGenericCode implements InputGenericCode<CSVReader> {

        @Override
        public String readLine(CSVReader x) {
            return x.readLine();
        }
    }

    static class CSVReader {

        public CSVReader(FileReader fileReader) {
            throw new RuntimeException("implement this");
        }

        public String readLine() {
            throw new RuntimeException("implement this");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String fileLocation, String extension) {
        FileReader fileReader = openFile(fileLocation);

        if (extension.equals("csv")) {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(fileReader);
            new CSVReaderInputGenericCode().genericAlgorithm(reader);
        } else {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            new BufferedReaderInputGenericCode().genericAlgorithm(reader);
        }

        // dataRow = reader.readLine();
    }

    public static FileReader openFile(String fileLocation) {
        FileReader fileReader = null;

        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(new File(fileLocation));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return fileReader;
    }
}
```

More complex way:

```
interface GenericExample {
    /**
     * All generic operations. 
     * 
     * @author jonasn
     *
     * @param <Input>
     */
    interface InputGenerics<Input> {
        String readLine(Input x);
    }
    interface InputGenericCode {
        public static <Input> void genericAlgorithm(Input x, InputGenerics<Input> generics) {
            // algorithm expressed generically here...
            for (;;) {
                String lineString = generics.readLine(x);
                System.out.println("" + lineString);
            }
        }
    }

    static class CSVReader {

        public CSVReader(FileReader fileReader) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public String readLine() {
            throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
        }
    }
    public class CSVReaderInputGenerics implements InputGenerics<CSVReader> {
        @Override 
        public String readLine(CSVReader x) {
            return x.readLine();
        }
    }
    public class BufferedReaderInputGenerics implements InputGenerics<BufferedReader> {
        @Override 
        public String readLine(BufferedReader x) {
            try {
                return x.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String fileLocation, String extension) {
        // String fileLocation = "whatever";
        // String extension = "";

        FileReader fileReader = null;
        // Object reader = null;
        String dataRow = null;

        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(new File(fileLocation));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if (extension.equals("csv")) 
        {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(fileReader);
            InputGenericCode.genericAlgorithm(reader, new CSVReaderInputGenerics());
        } 
        else 
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            InputGenericCode.genericAlgorithm(reader, new BufferedReaderInputGenerics());
        }  

        // dataRow = reader.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The proper way meaning I don't get a compiler error :)

Comment: @user1026110 The above code compiles fine :). Hope you'll like it/use it. There is a bit of complexity overhead, so it may not pay off until the 'generic part' gets large enough (complexity, number of type combinations etc).

Comment: Thank you so much! (I meant that my original code doesn't compile)

Comment: @user1026110 No prob, I had nothing else to do. If you like it, vote it up.